# C++ QNetworkAccessManager (Qt) in conjunction with openGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm really nooby with C++ (as my previous posts mention), however my friend suggested I work with QNetworkAccessManager if I want to send a HTTP GET request to send information.

I am currently working with openGL-es and want to do the following two lines of code to send the get request:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* netMan = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
netMan->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("something/?userID=1")));
```

However, it does not like the "this" because it is in the main() method and it does not reference a QObject (I'm guessing QApplication). When I get rid of the "this" my application builds, but just never loads (I put a "printf(1)" at the top which doesn't even run).

Any suggestions or alternatives on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

-James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in the `QNetworkAccessManager` constructor is only needed to specify a `QObject` based parent which will be responsible for cleaning up (deleting) your object later and isn't necessary if you plan to call `delete` on it yourself.

I'm not quite sure what you are referring to by "never loads" or where you put a `printf` but in order to get anything back, you need to actually keep the `QNetworkReply` pointer that is returned by the call to `get()`.

And to get anything from that, you need an event loop running. If your application is console only (no GUI), you can use a `QCoreApplication` object.

Try this minimal code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QNetworkAccessManager *netMan = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkReply *reply = netMan->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://google.com")));
    a.connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(quit()));
    a.exec();
    qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    delete netMan;
}
```